# Embeddings of hyperbolic $n$-manifolds in $R^{n+2}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Is there any <s>example of a</s> compact manifold $M$ of dimension $n>10000$
such that

1. $M$  admits an embedding into $\mathbb R^{n+2}$,
2. $M$ is hyperbolic; i.e.,  it admits a Riemannian metric with
   curvature $\equiv -1$?

---

More generally, are there some criteria sufficient for existence of embedding of compact manifolds $M^n$ of large dimension in $\mathbb R^{n+2}$?

Comment: As long as it embeds with a trivial normal bundle (which can be arranged by some restrictions on $M$), the manifold's fundamental class would be dual to a bounding $n+1$-manifold in $\mathbb R^{n+2}$.    

Comment: Dima: If immersion is enough for you, then every closed hyperbolic n-manifold has a finite cover which admits an immersion in ${\mathbb R}^{n+1}$ (Sullivan+Hirsch+Smale). On the other hand, we do not have any "examples" of hyperbolic n-manifolds for large n, where "example" means a description in terms of triangulation or handle decomposition. They are all described by algebraic means. We do not even have a single hyperbolic n-manifold or orbifold with known 1-st homology group (say, for $n\ge 10^4$). 

Comment: Also, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604045v1.pdf for a survey of the embedding theory. Unfortunately, all sufficient conditions for embeddings require high connectivity that hyperbolic manifolds will not have. 

Comment: Ryan, could you please expend a bit your comment? (I don't see straight away how it could help).

Misha, thank you for your comments. Probably I should not use the word "example" :). I mean, that I will be happy with just existence...    

Comment: I'm just running through the standard argument that co-dimension two knots have Seifert surfaces, but adapted to your case.  If $M$ embeds in $\mathbb R^{n+2}$, the complement of the embedding has $H^1 \simeq \mathbb Z$.  Represent that cohomology class as a map from the complement to the circle, and take the fiber of a regular value.  Provided the normal bundle to the embedded manifold $M$ is trivial we can ensure this is a Seifert surface / bounding manifold for $M$.  You could ensure the normal bundle is trivial by making $M$ orientable and $H^2 M$ trivial. 

Comment: @Ryan: This is just to note that there are no known examples of hyperbolic $n$-manifolds (for large $n$) with vanishing 2-nd Betti number (or any Betti number for this matter). For all what we know, they all may have nonzero 2nd Betti number. 